# XSLT transform with dynamic lookups

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I need to transform data that looks something like this. For each user, I need to read the idcode attribute, fetch the appropriate value from the idcode tag, and output them together. Users can have multiple comma separated idcodes. The list of users, ids per use and id lookup list can each be arbitrarily large.

Input:

```
<users>
  <user idcode="1">Doug Edmonds</user>
  <user idcode="2">Jay P. Dunn</user>
  <user idcode="4,5">Gerard A. Kriss</user>
  <user idcode="6">Kirk Korista</user>
  <idcode id="1">100</idcode>
  <idcode id="2">254</idcode>
  <idcode id="3">854</idcode>
  <idcode id="4">741</idcode>
  <idcode id="5">965</idcode>
  <idcode id="6">571</idcode>
</users>
```

Desired output:

```
<systemUser>Doug Edmonds</systemUser>
<systemId value="100"/>
<systemUser>Jay P. Dunn</systemUser>
<systemId value="254"/>
<systemUser>Gerard A. Kriss</systemUser>
<systemId value="741"/>
<systemId value="965"/>
<systemUser>Kirk Korista</systemUser>
<systemId value="571"/>
```

The xslt I've been tinkering with is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
                xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                exclude-result-prefixes="xhtml xsl xs">

    <xsl:output method="xhtml"/>

    <xsl:template match="header">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="users/user" />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="user">
        <xsl:variable name="userName" select="."/>
        <xsl:variable name="userId" select="./@idcode"/>
        <user>{$userName}</user>
        <xsl:variable name="tokenizedId" select="tokenize($userId,',')"/>
        <xsl:for-each select="$tokenizedId">
            <xsl:variable name="singleId" select="."/>
            <xsl:variable name="systemId" select="./users/idcode[@id = '{$singleId}']"/>
            <systemId" value="{$systemId}"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You used `./@idcode` when you really meant `../@idcode`.

Also note that the XPath `=` operator works against sequences, so you don't need `$singleId`.

How about:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
                xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                exclude-result-prefixes="xhtml xsl xs">

    <xsl:output method="xhtml"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

    <xsl:template match="user">
        <user><xsl:value-of select="." /></user>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="../idcode[@id = tokenize(current()/@idcode, ',')]" mode="systemId" />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="idcode" mode="systemId">
        <systemId value="{.}" />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="idcode" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

of course the same thing can be expressed with a for-each, if you prefer.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
                xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                exclude-result-prefixes="xhtml xsl xs">

    <xsl:output method="xhtml"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

    <xsl:template match="user">
        <user><xsl:value-of select="." /></user>
        <xsl:for-each select="../idcode[@id = tokenize(current()/@idcode, ',')]">
            <systemId value="{.}" />
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="idcode" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can declare a key to cross reference `idcode` and use it as following:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="xhtml xsl xs">
    <xsl:output method="xhtml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:key name="idcode" match="/users/idcode" use="@id"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <output>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="users/user" />
        </output>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="users/user">
        <systemUser>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </systemUser>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="key('idcode', tokenize(@idcode, ','))"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="idcode">
        <systemId value="{.}"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```